# Does this violate the notion of positive definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, control-theory

From a previous course in linear algebra, I was taught that a function is positive definite if it satisfies
$$\left< \vec x \mid v(\vec x) \mid \vec x\right>   > 0 $$
In simpler notation, 
$$\vec x^Tv(\vec x)\vec x> 0$$

But today in lecture the prof defined that a function is positive definite if 
$$v(\vec x) > 0$$ except at equilibrium points $\bar x$ where $$v(\bar x) = 0$$

This violates what I knew about positive definiteness in two folds, first we are forgetting about the quadratic form, second we allow this function to vanish at some equilibrium points.

Can someone check whether this new function still indeed satisfies the definition of positive definiteness?

Comment: I cannot make sense of your notation. Positive definiteness apples to bilinear forms, not functions. In what you write it would make more sense if $v(\vec x)$ were a linear operator, and one that _does not_ depend on $\vec x$ (after all it is _applied to_ $\vec x$ in the first two expressions, there is no need that ii depends itself on $\vec x$). But in the remainder that interpretation does not make sense either.

Comment: Please double check your notes and maybe edit the question to include the exact phrasing used in the previous course and the current course. As Marc pointed out, your notation and terminology do not agree with accepted conventions; it will help us to know if it is because your professors chose to use a convention slightly different from the standard ones, or if it is a case where you just misunderstood what your professor is trying to say. (incidentally, isn't this type of problem precisely what you should be asking your prof in his or her office hours?)